# Display data outputs strange results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data in a file that looks like this:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=Sveta
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=Jason
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason

[Profile2]
Name=Sarah
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/23mvfqcj.Sarah
```

I want to read all data and construct a `namedtuple` based on that data, but the output is quite strange, and I'm not sure how to explain it and what to do about it.

Here is what I tired:

```
def split_and_return_data(data_to_split):
    return data_to_split.split("=")[1]

def main():

    # read_profile_attributes returns a list containing the data
    profile_attributes = read_profile_attributes(profile_ini)

    # Ignore the first 3 elements
    list_of_firefox_profiles = list_of_profile_attributes[3:len(profile_attributes)]
    firefox_profile = namedtuple("Profile", ["Name", "IsRelative", "Path", "Default"])


    name = None
    isRelative = None
    path = None
    default = None

    for profile_attribute in list_of_firefox_profiles:
        if profile_attribute and "Name" in profile_attribute:
            name = split_and_return_data(profile_attribute)
        elif profile_attribute and "IsRelative" in profile_attribute:
            isRelative = split_and_return_data(profile_attribute)
        elif profile_attribute and "Path" in profile_attribute:
            path = split_and_return_data(profile_attribute)
        elif profile_attribute and "Default" in profile_attribute:
            default = split_and_return_data(profile_attribute)
        print("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(name, isRelative, path, default))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
None, None, None, None
Sveta, None, None, None
Sveta, 1, None, None
Sveta, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, None
Sveta, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, 1
Sveta, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, 1
Sveta, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, 1
Jason, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, 1
Jason, 1, Profiles/lqtrtj3x.Sveta, 1
Jason, 1, Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason, 1
Jason, 1, Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason, 1
Jason, 1, Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason, 1
Sarah, 1, Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason, 1
Sarah, 1, Profiles/er5rtak4.Jason, 1
Sarah, 1, Profiles/23mvfqcj.Sarah, 1
Sarah, 1, Profiles/23mvfqcj.Sarah, 1
```

I want to take the `Name`, `IsRelative`, `Path`, and `Default`(`None` if `Default` isn't there) and create a `namedtuple`. I know I'm printing the results in my example, but if I created `namedtuple` and store it in a `list`, it creates a `namedtuple` with all the data seen in the output. There should only be 3 `namedtuples` stored in the `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library for this called configparser

It might be easier than what you are attempting.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html